# How to check if user hovering over a div and keep alive popover for certain time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I am showing a popover on mouse enter and hide on mouse leave. My code is below

```
   $(document).on('mouseenter', '.chat-user', function () {
    var $popover = $('#custom-popover');
    $popover.show();
    });

    $(document).on('mouseleave', '.chat-user', function () {
    var $popover = $('#custom-popover');
                $popover.hide();
    });
    Popover code:

        <div class='popover left details-popover' style="display: none;border-radius: 0px !important;" id="custom-popover">

            <div class="popover-content" id="details-container">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

But I need my function on mouseleave as below

```
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.chat-user', function () {

// before I hide the popover I have to check the following things
1) after mouse leave I have to keep the popover alive for 50 miliseconds 
2) after 50 miliseconds I will hide the popover if 
3) user is not hovering over the popover

    var $popover = $('#custom-popover');
                $popover.hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a timeout in the mouseleave event, and clear the timeout if the user enters again in the mouseenter event.

```
var timer = null;

$(document).on('mouseenter', '.chat-user', function () {
    var $popover = $('#custom-popover');
    $popover.show();

    if (timer != null) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.chat-user', function () {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        var $popover = $('#custom-popover');
        $popover.hide();
    }, 50);
});
```

Comment: but before I hide the popover I have to check if cursor is present on the popover. That is if a user is hovering over the popover then popover should not hide and when user leave popover, it will hide

Comment: @user3128796 this code does exactly that. Not sure I understand what you mean? [See this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VuLnY/) for a live example. Here I have increased the timeout from 50 ms to 2000 ms to make it easier to see how it works (50 ms is a really, really short time...)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `.delay()`.

```
$("#custom-popover").delay(500).fadeOut();
```

http://api.jquery.com/delay/